# (Android)Null check for EditText in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parseint

I'm having trouble performing a null check on an EditText found in my ListView's row.  Basically I want to extract information from the `milesEntry` EditText view via `Integer.parseInt(((EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.milesEntry)).getText().toString());` whenever I press the `save` button within a specific listview row.  Everything works fine when I fill out the `milesEntry` EditText field within a row with actual data and execute the parse, but if I click `save` without adding data the to the `milesEntry` field my application crashes.  Here is my debug code for the issue

```
           View row = entries.getChildAt(indexInAdapter - firstVisible);


            int milesFromTheEditText;
            EditText e = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.milesEntry);

            if(e.getText().toString == null) {
                System.out.println("ITS NULL");
            }else if(e.getText().toString() == "") {
                System.out.println("EMPTY STRING");
            }else {
            System.out.print("NEITHER");
```

The issue is whenever I click on the `save` button while the `milesEntry` EditText field is empty on my application "NEITHER" comes up, as in it is neither an empty nor a null string, making it impossible to manually catch the exception that is causing my application to crash.

Also, I do not set any text in my initialization of `milesEntry` either. Just a hint, which is set to "Miles".

EDIT: SOLVED

I found that `if(e.getText().toString().length == 0)` will catch the exception for me.

Comment: Check the Logcat for the exact exception.

Comment: You can also use utility method `TextUtils.isEmpty()`, which encapsulates length and nullity checks

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct!!!

```
if(e.getText().toString == null)
```

If the `getText()` returns `null`, you will get a NPE. The correct way is as follows:

```
if (e.getText() == null || e.getText().toString() == null || e.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use from this way :

```
String value = e.getText().toString();
if(value.length() > 0){
   //DO
}else{
  //DO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"edittext" can be null object. And

```
edittext.getText()
```

cannot be null but can be empty string.

try like this

```
    if(e == null){
        //EditText is null
    }else{
        String temp = e.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(temp)){//check string is empty or not
            //there is no data
        }
    }
```